# What did Oracle Cloud do, so I could sudo without password on SSH session?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, pam

I noticed that Oracle Cloud's pre-generated key pair could login into Linux server without password, and sudo without password, too. I can't reproduce this situation anywhere else I known.

The difference between Oracle Cloud and others is that it also generated a user `ubuntu` (For Ubuntu. And for Oracle Linux, the default user is `opc`. Whether the distro I use, An `opc` user is always generated) at OOBE. It seems that Oracle Cloud servers do not use `root` user by default. So I realized that there's an `Oracle Cloud Agent` installed, works with sudo user `opc`. Is that software handled the sudo authorization? (But I checked `/etc/pam.d` and some other places, these files are remained vanilla.)

The other sites told me to set up a pam module `libpam-ssh-agent-auth`, but that's a outdated project, without update for years. I tried on many server and won't work. (Though many distro didn't remove this pam module from package manager)

It would be appreciated if someone could tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

**Sudo**

To allow users of the sudo group (or equivalent) the sudo configuration can be changed.
Add this to */etc/sudoers*
(Use visudo as root)

```
%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Do note that the user needs to be member of the sudo group.

Or just one specific user:

```
username_here       ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

**SSH key**

To be able to login as a user without a password your public SSH key needs to be added to the account you wish to login to.

The proper way of doing this is by using ssh-copy-id

```
ssh-copy-id user@servername.example
```

This will add your public key to the specified user's homefolder under *.ssh/authorized_keys*

You can copy it manually as well if you wish.
Just copy the output of this file(your local machine)  into the *.ssh/authorized_keys* file of the user (on the server):

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: I know how to SSH without password, but I wonder without modify /etc/sudoers, is any other way to do this?

Comment: The recommended way is using visudo (https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/1.8.13/visudo.man/). However you can directly edit it if you are careful. If your cloudprovider supports boot scripts you can just append it with some simple bash to slip it in pre-deploy.

Comment: Typically modern sudo implementations have an `#Include /etc/sudoers.d` directive to load additional sudo polices from the `/etc/sudoers.d/`  drop in directory. That allows much easier (automated)  deployment for sudo policies than adding them to  a single flat file

Comment: @diya You are right! I do found the additional policy in `/etc/sudoers.d`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Typically cloud images run [`cloudinit`](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)   when they are launched to initialize and customize the generic image for an unique instance.

Cloudnit can and usually does perform generic tasks but is generally also configured to interact with the specific cloud providers meta data service to load Vendor and/or User Data. That mechanism is usually what provisions in the instance the personal public ssh key you uploaded to the cloud provider and what enables you to log in with the associated private key.

Cloud init can do many things, including deploying users, set up ssh keys and/or passwords  and  sudo rights for those newly deployed users.

How to enable your own User-Data to (further) customize what cloud init does is cloud vendor specific.